# Laravel: Using resource controller correctly

Tags: laravel, controller, resources

I have a bunch of photos located in `public/test_images`.

I created a controller to handle image requests. I did it like this:

In `routes/web.php`, I wrote the line:

```
Route::resource('image', 'ImageController');
```

And in the terminal I wrote:

```
php artisan make:controller ImageController --resource
```

Now I have the ImageController file in `app/Http/Controllers`.

My goal is to be able to do this:

```
http://localhost:8000/image/5
```

and then get an image returned. But this doesn't work. I get nothing returned. Same thing if I just write `http://localhost:8000/image`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show us your show method in your ImageController ? Did you also made a php artisan route:list to be sure the route was there ?

Comment: I didn't. I just followed the guide I linked to.

Comment: The method is the auto generated one. It looks empty, do I need to write it myself?

Comment: public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

Comment: Of course you need to write it yourself. RessourceController are just a base for your project which generate all the CRUD methods necessary. But no code will be written on this on ... 

What show($id) is supposed to do is to get your Image with the ID = $id ... But you have to code it down.